# Can't handshake with minecraft server using sockets with c# How?

Tags: java, c#, sockets, minecraft

I want to make mini minecraft client which joins to minecraft server and types anything i want. But firstly, i want to get server's MOTD message. But couldn't can you help me about this?

```
tatic void Main(string[] args)
    {
        s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        s.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.29"), 25565));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
        Task.Run(() => SendCommands());
        while (true)
        {
            s.Receive(buffer);
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
            buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
        }
    }

    static void SendCommands()
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        int protocolVersion = -1;
        string svaddress = "102.168.1.29";
        ushort port = 25565;
        int nextstate = 1;
        ms.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(protocolVersion));
        ms.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(svaddress));
        ms.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(port));
        ms.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(nextstate));
        s.Send(ms.ToArray());
        ms.Close();
        s.Send(new byte[0]);
    }
```

I think this problem is because of VarInt variable. I am using normal Integer istead of using VarInt but i couldn't figure out how this VarInt works. Check it out https://wiki.vg/Protocol#VarInt_and_VarLong

Check out this too minecraft server protocol https://wiki.vg/Protocol

And i get this error for response:

?{"translate":"disconnect.genericReason","with":["Internal Exception: io.netty.handler.codec.CorruptedFrameException: length wider than 21-bit"]}

Comment: Why are you in two different subnets? 102.168.1.29 and "192.168.1.29.

Comment: To get MOTD (message of the day) you need to login.  So you first need to complete a connection and supply username and password before getting the MOTD.

Comment: You are wrong, i don't need to login to get motd message. You can get motd message with cracked client too. I just need to know how to convert VarInt with c#, about subnets yea i typed wrong i fixed it. Check this for getting motd message i couldn't make this https://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping

Comment: TCP and UDP are IP Protocols.  SLP is also a IP Protocol.  The IP header has a field for protocols like TCP, UDP, and SLP.  SLP is not a standard protocol in the Net Library so to impliment SLP you either have to use c++ to specify the protocol or use the ws2_32 library to make the connection.  See www.pinvoke.net